# Calculate Pct Change Adjusted by Dividends

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Dg0JYXoQyqIVokrVoSJOBogJw_bDCY-IoBGtleOlm8/edit?usp=sharing

I need to calculate the Pct_Change_Adjusted Column in pandas:

Pct_Change_Adjusted = ((Value[1] + Dividend[1]) / Value[0] - 1)

For example, for row #3, # 4 y #5 (Googlesheet) the data is:

> 2019-01-02 9072    A   1020.0000   0.0000  0.0200  0.0200  9072A
>
> 2019-01-03 9072    A   1040.4000   0.0000  0.0200  0.0200 9072A
>
> 2019-01-04 9072    A   1009.1880   52.0200 -0.0300 0.0200 9072A

Pct_Change_Adjusted (Row # 4) = ((1.040.4000 + 0.0000) / (1020.0000) - 1) = 0.0200

Pct_Change_Adjusted (Row # 5) = ((1.009.1880 + 52.02000) / (1040.4000) - 1) = 0.0200

Is there a way to do this fast with pct_change? (instead of iterating with conditions through the data)

So far my code for Pct_Change is:

df.groupby(df[6])[3].pct_change(1)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing but more elaborate:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

s = '''
Date    Fund_ID Fund_Series Value   Dividend
2019-01-02 9072 A 1020.0000 0.0000
2019-01-03 9072 A 1040.4000 0.0000
2019-01-04 9072 A 1009.1880 52.0200 
''';

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s),sep='\s')
print(df)

         Date  Fund_ID Fund_Series     Value  Dividend
0  2019-01-02     9072           A  1020.000      0.00
1  2019-01-03     9072           A  1040.400      0.00
2  2019-01-04     9072           A  1009.188     52.02

df['Pct_Change_Adjusted'] = df.groupby(['Fund_ID', 'Fund_Series'], as_index=False) \
                              .apply(lambda x: (x.Value + x.Dividend)/x.Value.shift()-1) \
                              .reset_index(drop=True).values[0]

print(df)

         Date  Fund_ID Fund_Series     Value  Dividend  Pct_Change_Adjusted
0  2019-01-02     9072           A  1020.000      0.00                  NaN
1  2019-01-03     9072           A  1040.400      0.00                 0.02
2  2019-01-04     9072           A  1009.188     52.02                 0.02
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, most likely, you can do the following:

```
df['Pct_Change_Adjusted'] = df.groupby(['Fund_ID', 'Fund_Series'], as_index=False) \
                              .apply(lambda x: (x.Value + x.Dividend)/x.Value.shift()-1) \
                              .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```